# Cloth simulation - simulate 2 unlinked meshes together as one

Tags: mesh, physics, vertices, cloth-simulation

Gentlemen, I have a problem with the cloth simulation. **The object I am simulating consists of 2 or more parts that are not interconnected. As a result, the simulation treats them as two separate objects.**

How can I make them behave as a single one?

*For example:* **I am modeling the German flag. It has 3 rectangular parts (Black, Red, Yellow).** And the sews have stitches (which is another separate object).

Now, I want the entire flag to fall onto something but all these individual pieces don't interact as one. What is the solution? Do I need to merge it somehow? (If so, how? Boolean operations...?)

Comment: You have to use one mesh. You can assign different materials for each part or you can use a texture file with the flag's pattern. Try to solve the sewing with normal and/or height map without a real thread model.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about that too! But when you solve the sewing using height map, how do you assign a different material to it then? It won't be possible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the stitches or other details can be represented by some cubes close to the flag geometry.

[image: stitches]

Duplicate the Flag mesh. The *FlagDupe* should also do the same simulation as the original. We will create a cage from it for the extras.

Add a displace modifier, and a solidify modifier. The value of the second modifier should be twice the value of the first modifier.

[image: modifier stack]

Select the stitched extra object, add a MeshCage Modifier to them and bind the object to the *FlagDupe* by clicking on the **bind** button.

[image: bind]

The bound object will follow the *FlageDupe* object.

[image: simulation result]

Comment: That is an interesting solution! Thanks for that!